# Can I use any XMPP Clients with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, azure, amazon-ec2, xmpp

is it possible or recommended to use any `XMPP Clients` to send & receive messages with ASP.NET? I have a AWS EC2 Micro Instance, Azure Webrole Small Instances and another Small Instance reserved for websites. I have tried to achieve this with `ASP.NET & Jabber-Net` but couldn't make it work. I don't want to receive the messages on any JS clients; I want to process the messages on the server itself.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? XMPP is a real-time messaging protocol whereas ASP.NET/HTTP is the opposite.

Comment: @FrazellThomas I am trying to receive and process the messages sent by Gtalk & other Jabber users to my registered users. Also I want to be able to send messages to Gtalk users.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're attempting to do, but what you described is outside of the scope of ASP.NET. Most apps of this type would use something like JavaScript or ActiveX or something to allow a real-time tie in. If this **must** be server side alone (e.g. the user won't be logged in) then you would need to build an XMPP processor (built on something like `libpurple`) and bridge it to your app using something like MSMQ or DB tables etc.

Comment: @FrazellThomas okay... I am trying to integrate GTalk into my existing messaging App. Simply what I'm trying to do is to send & receive messages on-behalf of the users. The messages will be processed on the server and some db logic will be applied here. So, I need to create new Jabber IDs on runtime, and must be able to connect as many users. Hope that this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no problem. We have done similar stuff before. You can create as many persistent XMPP sessions as you need on behalf of your users for sending and receiving xmpp stanzas.
The only problems we have seen are security restrictions for IIS on many web hosters which don't allow you to create sockets.

see also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/330a99hc(v=vs.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649312.aspx